# Why do we not have splice in array collection?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

From what I know the whole idea behind having collection classes is introduce extra wrapper methods which will be handy for developers.

Then why does ArrayCollection in Flex not seem to have some methods that array has.
ArrayCollection does not have a copy, concat, join or splice methods which return a new array so we need to do the copy manually? Or I am missing something in here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the methods are not there. There is no published reason for the decision, that I can find.

If I had to guess, and this is only a wild guess, I would say that the business side of things prevailed when Adobe made this call. It's impossible to guess could be anyone of a dozen of factors - examples include not having enough developers to fully flesh out each data structure, or not enough time before the last release, or not enough pressure from clients for this kind of work, or not enough testing/support/maintenance resources.